# Book multiple flights with Ryanair and save on Administration Fee

Tags: air-travel, bookings, fees-and-charges, low-cost-carriers, ryanair

I need to book 2 different flights with Ryanair, but if I book them separately I have to pay GBP 6 as administration fees because I'm paying with a Visa Debit (and most cards are charged GBP 6).
I can not find the link to add another flight to my booking. I know easyjet supports it, but does Ryanair do it ?

Maybe there is a way to book through another web site (opodo...) that would solve the issue...

Comment: Come on - it's not an "administration fee" they want you to avoid. It's a marketing gag to split the fare into different smaller parts with different names, so they can advertise with "A to B for GBP 19!" while you still pay GBP 60 for the seat.
Take the train for inner-country trips in europe. It's usually not slower, but you can travel city-city and you wont be stuck on a small airport in the middle of the countryside, 60km away from advertised "B" :)

Comment: Though it's true that, sometimes, trains are a viable alternative, they tend to be more expensive (though not always) and certainly, on longer journeys, won't be faster.

Comment: Even if you book for two people *at the same time*, the "administration fee" will be charged double.  There's no way to avoid it.  In fact it may be advantageous to book for each person separately: I found that there is a single cheap seat left, when booking for two, both will be offered the more expensive seats.  If booking separately, one will get the cheap seat and one the more expensive one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nope. Two different flights means two bookings on Ryanair. Annoying, but true.

Comment: Also per person. Possibly less annoying than a single "admin" fee.

Answer (score 6):

No probably not. However you should look into getting a prepaid mastercard (you can get them online) if you are booking lots of flights with ryanair. it's usually cheaper.

Comment: They don't charge extra for debit card any more. £6 "admin" per person per leg. (Unless you use their "Ryanair Cash Passport" - costs £6, minimum loading £150. I can't imagine they sell many.)